# OpenVPN client connects to server, but no internet. Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-18.04, openvpn

OpenVPN client connects to server. But no internet. Nevertheless I can ping from terminal 8.8.8.8 unless i open any web page in browser. After opening any web page i can not also ping Google Public DNS.
I have Ubuntu 18.04.

We have tried also public openvpn configs. They also do not work from Ubuntu. But same config works nicely from Mac.

What could be the issue? Bellow i have posted logs:

```
vlad@vlad-ThinkPad:~/keys/vpn$ sudo openvpn --config vladv.ovpn 
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645618 Current Parameter Settings:
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645644   config = 'vladv.ovpn'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645649   mode = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645652   persist_config = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645656   persist_mode = 1
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645659   show_ciphers = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645663   show_digests = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645666   show_engines = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645669   genkey = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645672   key_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645676   show_tls_ciphers = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645680   connect_retry_max = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645687 Connection profiles [0]:
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645691   proto = udp
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645695   local = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645699   local_port = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645703   remote = '52.204.183.105'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645707   remote_port = '1194'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645737   remote_float = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645741   bind_defined = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645745   bind_local = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645750   bind_ipv6_only = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645754   connect_retry_seconds = 5
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645757   connect_timeout = 120
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645774   socks_proxy_server = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645778   socks_proxy_port = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645801   tun_mtu = 1500
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645806   tun_mtu_defined = ENABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645810   link_mtu = 1500
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645815   link_mtu_defined = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645819   tun_mtu_extra = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645823   tun_mtu_extra_defined = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645827   mtu_discover_type = -1
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645831   fragment = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645835   mssfix = 1450
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645839   explicit_exit_notification = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645844 Connection profiles END
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645848   remote_random = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645852   ipchange = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645856   dev = 'tun'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645860   dev_type = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645864   dev_node = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645868   lladdr = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645872   topology = 1
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645876   ifconfig_local = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645880   ifconfig_remote_netmask = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645884   ifconfig_noexec = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645888   ifconfig_nowarn = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645893   ifconfig_ipv6_local = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645897   ifconfig_ipv6_netbits = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645901   ifconfig_ipv6_remote = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645905   shaper = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645910   mtu_test = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645914   mlock = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645918   keepalive_ping = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645922   keepalive_timeout = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645926   inactivity_timeout = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645930   ping_send_timeout = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645934   ping_rec_timeout = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645938   ping_rec_timeout_action = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645942   ping_timer_remote = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645946   remap_sigusr1 = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645950   persist_tun = ENABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645954   persist_local_ip = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645958   persist_remote_ip = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645962   persist_key = ENABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645967   passtos = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645971   resolve_retry_seconds = 1000000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645975   resolve_in_advance = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645979   username = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645983   groupname = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645987   chroot_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645991   cd_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645995   writepid = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=645999   up_script = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646003   down_script = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646007   down_pre = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646011   up_restart = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646015   up_delay = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646019   daemon = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646023   inetd = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646027   log = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646031   suppress_timestamps = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646035   machine_readable_output = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646039   nice = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646043   verbosity = 4
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646047   mute = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646051   gremlin = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646055   status_file = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646059   status_file_version = 1
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646063   status_file_update_freq = 60
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646067   occ = ENABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646071   rcvbuf = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646075   sndbuf = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646079   mark = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646083   sockflags = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646087   fast_io = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646091   comp.alg = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646095   comp.flags = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646099   route_script = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646103   route_default_gateway = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646107   route_default_metric = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646112   route_noexec = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646116   route_delay = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646120   route_delay_window = 30
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646124   route_delay_defined = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646128   route_nopull = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646131   route_gateway_via_dhcp = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646135   allow_pull_fqdn = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646139   management_addr = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646144   management_port = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646148   management_user_pass = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646152   management_log_history_cache = 250
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646156   management_echo_buffer_size = 100
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646160   management_write_peer_info_file = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646164   management_client_user = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646168   management_client_group = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646173   management_flags = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646177   shared_secret_file = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646181   key_direction = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646185   ciphername = 'AES-128-GCM'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646189   ncp_enabled = ENABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646193   ncp_ciphers = 'AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646198   authname = 'SHA256'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646202   prng_hash = 'SHA1'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646206   prng_nonce_secret_len = 16
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646210   keysize = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646214   engine = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646218   replay = ENABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646222   mute_replay_warnings = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646226   replay_window = 64
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646230   replay_time = 15
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646235   packet_id_file = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646239   use_iv = ENABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646243   test_crypto = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646247   tls_server = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646251   tls_client = ENABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646255   key_method = 2
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646259   ca_file = '[[INLINE]]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646263   ca_path = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646267   dh_file = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646272   cert_file = '[[INLINE]]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646276   extra_certs_file = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646280   priv_key_file = '[[INLINE]]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646284   pkcs12_file = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646288   cipher_list = 'TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646292   tls_verify = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646297   tls_export_cert = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646301   verify_x509_type = 2
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646305   verify_x509_name = 'server_MFHCkWn6oZwnN5iF'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646309   crl_file = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646313   ns_cert_type = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646317   remote_cert_ku[i] = 65535
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646321   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646326   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646330   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646334   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646338   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646342   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646346   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646350   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646354   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646358   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646362   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646366   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646370   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646374   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646378   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646382   remote_cert_eku = 'TLS Web Server Authentication'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646387   ssl_flags = 192
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646391   tls_timeout = 2
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646395   renegotiate_bytes = -1
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646399   renegotiate_packets = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646403   renegotiate_seconds = 3600
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646407   handshake_window = 60
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646411   transition_window = 3600
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646415   single_session = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646420   push_peer_info = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646424   tls_exit = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646428   tls_auth_file = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646432   tls_crypt_file = '[[INLINE]]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646436   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646440   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646444   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646448   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646453   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646457   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646461   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646465   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646469   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646473   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646477   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646481   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646485   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646490   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646494   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646498   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646502   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646507   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646511   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646515   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646519   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646523   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646527   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646531   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646535   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646539   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646543   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646547   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646551   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646555   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646559   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646563   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646567   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646571   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646575   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646579   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646583   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646587   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646592   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646596   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646600   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646604   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646608   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646612   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646616   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646620   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646624   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646628   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646632   pkcs11_pin_cache_period = -1
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646636   pkcs11_id = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646640   pkcs11_id_management = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646647   server_network = 0.0.0.0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646653   server_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646657   server_network_ipv6 = ::
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646661   server_netbits_ipv6 = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646666   server_bridge_ip = 0.0.0.0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646670   server_bridge_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646675   server_bridge_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646679   server_bridge_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646683   ifconfig_pool_defined = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646688   ifconfig_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646692   ifconfig_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646697   ifconfig_pool_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646701   ifconfig_pool_persist_filename = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646705   ifconfig_pool_persist_refresh_freq = 600
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646709   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_defined = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646714   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_base = ::
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646718   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_netbits = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646723   n_bcast_buf = 256
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646727   tcp_queue_limit = 64
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646732   real_hash_size = 256
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646738   virtual_hash_size = 256
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646743   client_connect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646750   learn_address_script = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646757   client_disconnect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646763   client_config_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646770   ccd_exclusive = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646776   tmp_dir = '/tmp'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646782   push_ifconfig_defined = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646789   push_ifconfig_local = 0.0.0.0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646796   push_ifconfig_remote_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646802   push_ifconfig_ipv6_defined = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646809   push_ifconfig_ipv6_local = ::/0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646815   push_ifconfig_ipv6_remote = ::
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646822   enable_c2c = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646828   duplicate_cn = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646834   cf_max = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646840   cf_per = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646846   max_clients = 1024
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646852   max_routes_per_client = 256
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646859   auth_user_pass_verify_script = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646866   auth_user_pass_verify_script_via_file = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646873   auth_token_generate = DISABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646879   auth_token_lifetime = 0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646885   port_share_host = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646890   port_share_port = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646894   client = ENABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646898   pull = ENABLED
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646902   auth_user_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646908 OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Sep  5 2018
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=646916 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017, LZO 2.08
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=647323 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=647338 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=647344 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=647351 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=647400 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1156 EF:94 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=647415 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1450 EF:121 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=647428 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1549,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher AES-128-GCM,auth [null-digest],keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=647432 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1549,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher AES-128-GCM,auth [null-digest],keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=647440 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]52.204.183.105:1194
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=647453 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=647458 UDP link local: (not bound)
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=647463 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]52.204.183.105:1194
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=767926 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]52.204.183.105:1194, sid=7d35d5a3 0dd6547d
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=941133 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=cn_Sr53cvp1BEzBy5Xw
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=941839 VERIFY KU OK
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=941883 Validating certificate extended key usage
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=941915 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=941942 VERIFY EKU OK
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=941966 VERIFY X509NAME OK: CN=server_MFHCkWn6oZwnN5iF
Thu Mar 14 15:52:01 2019 us=941991 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server_MFHCkWn6oZwnN5iF
Thu Mar 14 15:52:02 2019 us=350393 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, 256 bit EC, curve: prime256v1
Thu Mar 14 15:52:02 2019 us=350479 [server_MFHCkWn6oZwnN5iF] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]52.204.183.105:1194
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=487988 SENT CONTROL [server_MFHCkWn6oZwnN5iF]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686005 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,dhcp-option DNS 172.31.0.2,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.3 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-128-GCM'
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686251 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686285 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686301 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686317 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686331 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686351 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686371 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1624
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686388 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686424 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1552 D:1450 EF:52 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686622 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-GCM' initialized with 128 bit key
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686650 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-GCM' initialized with 128 bit key
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=686896 ROUTE_GATEWAY 10.1.1.0/255.255.252.0 IFACE=wlp3s0 HWADDR=00:28:f8:68:b4:2e
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=687498 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=687626 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=687681 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=687738 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=690849 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 10.8.0.3/24 broadcast 10.8.0.255
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=693274 /sbin/ip route add 52.204.183.105/32 via 10.1.1.0
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=694206 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=695281 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1
Thu Mar 14 15:52:03 2019 us=697189 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue and the below solution helped me.

Open the below file using the following command

```
sudo vim /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

And, at the end add the below two lines and save exit the file:-

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

and then run the below command:-

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

I hope this helps!!